# How to verify two distinct values belong to a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have the following MySQL query. As you can see in the last line, it asks for the filter_id to be either 51 or 8.

How can I modify this query to make sure the products that are returned are only products that have BOTH filter IDs.

What I did: I tried adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pf.filter_id) >=2` based on other answers in this forum but it did not help.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total
FROM ocb3l_product_to_category p2c 
    LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
    AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    AND p2c.category_id = '146' 
    AND pf.filter_id IN (51,8)
```

P.S. This query is used in an OpenCart shop to get the total number of products on the category pages.

Comment: Most of the predicates in the `WHERE` clause are negating the "outerness" of the `LEFT JOIN` operations.

Comment: @spencer7593, the query is coming from an e-commerce application, it's not written by me. The query works fine however, I'm just trying to modify its outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pf.filter_id) >=2` clause will work, if you were to `GROUP BY` the `product_id`.

One approach is to use an inline view (derived table) so that this check can be performed for each product_id. The result from that can be joined to the other tables.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fp.product_id) AS total
  FROM ( 
         SELECT p.product_id
           FROM ocb3l_product p
           JOIN ocb3l_product_filter pf
             ON pf.product_id = p.product_id
            AND pf.filter_id IN (51,8)
          WHERE p.status = '1'
            AND p.date_available <= NOW()
          GROUP BY p.product_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pf.filter_id) = 2
       ) fp
  JOIN ocb3l_product_to_category p2c
       ON p2c.product_id = fp.product_id
       AND p2c.category_id = '146'
  JOIN ocb3l_product_to_store p2s
       ON p2s.product_id = fp.product_id
       AND p2s.store_id = '0'
  JOIN ocb3l_product_description pd
       ON pd.product_id = fp.product_id
       AND pd.language_id = '1'
```

Comment: @farjam If you have more filter IDs to filter for then use this approach.

Comment: @farjam: after reviewing this again, I think just adding a **`GROUP BY p.product_id`** (along with the **`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pf.filter_id) >= 2`** ) to your original query would be sufficient to meet the specification. Given the JOIN operations are all based on `p.product_id`, that should give a resultset equivalent to that returned by the query in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add another JOINed copy of the `product_filter` table like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total
  FROM ocb3l_product_to_category p2c 
  LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) 
  LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_filter pf2 ON (p2c.product_id = pf2.product_id) /*new*/ 
  LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product p  ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id) 
  LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
  LEFT JOIN ocb3l_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
 WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
   AND p.status = '1' 
   AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
   AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
   AND p2c.category_id = '146' 
   AND pf.filter_id = 51   /*used to be IN (51,8)*/
   AND pf2.filter_id = 8   /*new*/
```

Comment: It works great for two filters, but what if I have more than 2 filters? Like 5 filters? I think adding additional joins would be overkill.

Comment: Overkill or not, that's the way this tag / value scheme for handling attributes works.

Comment: @farjam I like this query because it does not use sub-queries. But it is usable only if there is a need for 2-3 filter IDs. I do not recommend such approach in the case you have more...